# Easy readout from QDataStream to QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qt5.4

I am reading from a binary file, and want to insert into a QList. Is there an easier way to do the following? (e.g. in one line)

```
QStringList traceNames;

for(qint64 i=0; i<numTraces; i++)
{
  QString name;
  stream >> name;
  traceNames << name;
}
```

`stream` is a `QDataStream`.

I was thinking something like `traceNames << stream` (which did not work).

Comment: QDataStream & operator>>(QDataStream & in, QStringList & list)

Comment: stream >> traceNames;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QStringList` has serialization operators implemented, but it will only work for data streams which were serialized from a `QStringList` to begin with.

```
  QStringList l;
  l << "aaa" << "bbb" << "ccc";
  QBuffer buf;
  QDataStream stream(&buf);
  buf.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

  stream << l;
  buf.seek(0);

  QStringList l1;
  stream >> l1;
  qDebug() << l1; // works as expected
```

Here is the hex dump of a serialized `QStringList` with the three test strings in it:

```
00 00 00 03 00 00 00 06 00 61 00 61 00 61 00 00 00 06 00 62 00 62 00 62 00 00 00 06 00 63 00 63 00 63
```

And here is the one with only the three test strings, without the `QStringList`:

```
00 00 00 06 00 61 00 61 00 61 00 00 00 06 00 62 00 62 00 62 00 00 00 06 00 63 00 63 00 63
```

As you can see they are different, therefore you cannot deserialize `QStringList` from a data stream which was not serialized from a `QStringList`.

So in case your binary file is composed of serialized `QStrings` then you've already figured out the most straightforward approach.

However, notice that the two stream are almost identical except the first 4 bytes. Technically, you could prepend those bytes to a data stream that contains only `QString`s and deserialize it into a `QStringList`:

```
  QByteArray rawData;
  QFile f("d:\\serializedStrings.bin");
  f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  rawData = f.readAll();

  rawData.prepend(QByteArray::fromHex("00000003"));

  QBuffer buf(&rawData);
  QDataStream in(&buf);
  buf.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

  QStringList slist;
  in >> slist;
  qDebug() << slist; // it works
```

Although it is arguable whether this qualifies for "easy"... Also note that the 3 is not some magic number, it is the number of strings in the string list. That's where your number goes in.